# AM2NF6G-VSTA Motherboard NIC connection

Tags: connection, network-adapter

I own a ASROCK AM2NF6G-VSTA motherboard. My integrated network card gives me the error 651 whenever I try to connect using a PPPoE connection.
It always stays at 0 for received bytes but the sent bytes are adding up.

I also tried adding a dedicated NIC and this has both sent/received bytes at zero regardless of activity.

Also checked the cabling and RJ45 sockets. Tried restarting the pc, disabling/enabling the onboard NIC.

What else can I do?
And why is this happening?

Comment: PPPoE to where exactly?  At the moment all we know is that you have a motherboard with ethernet, not what you are connecting to.  I assume you are using some kind of modem or wiring your ISP or network administrator has provided but we cannot tell from your question.  Please edit to provide more detail.

Comment: @Mokubai I didn't give that data because I tested the connection on other computers. It works fine on any other pc except this one.